# Unzip a .zip which includes directories with spaces in Name

Tags: ls, filenames, quoting, zip

I have a problem with unzipping my transfered `.zip` file.

Firstly, I zipped a owncloud data directory with the encryption parameter. Then I transfered it to my new Server und would like to unzip it there.

Now I have the problem that I have directories in my `.zip` file, which have spaces in the directory name like `Jan Tester`.

On my old Server was the direcory displayed without quotes in the directory name. After I unziped the file, every folder name with a space in name was surrounded with quotes. For example `'Jan Tester'`

I would be very greatefull for any kind of help, so that I could use my old file structure on my new Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a problem with your zip file. Unzipping doesn't put quotes around file names. It's the `ls` command from GNU coreutils (the one found on non-embedded Linux and sometimes on other systems) that does this. It started doing this by default with release 8.25 which came out in 2016, so it's very likely that your desktop is running a newer version, but your server is running a long-time support distribution with an older version.

You can pass different options to `ls` to change the way it quotes file names. For example, `ls -Q` consistently puts double quotes around each file name.

Comment: So you mean, that it is only a display error from ls and everything is normal in the file structure?

Then I'll try to migrate the files to the new owncloud / nextcloud structure.

THX

Comment: @Jan It's not really a display _error_, `ls` does that _on purpose_ so you can easily copy the file name from a listing and paste it into a command. But yes, the quotes aren't really there in the actual names.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in newer versions of Linux. All of my production machines run Debian, and I've noticed that on newer versions of Debian 10+ directories with spaces in them automatically get quoted when I do an "ls". The data is the same, the way it's presented on the screen is what's different. Nothing to worry about.